# Why 'flex-direction:row' does not arrange all elements in a single row (+ a placement issue)?

Tags: css, less, flexbox

Here is my html markup:

```
<div class="expander-container" data-css="expander-container">
  <div class="top-comment-container" data-css="top-comment-container">
    <a class="expand-anchor" data-css="expand-anchor" >
      <div><span class="alternate-color icon-next arrow" 
                  data-css="alternate-color icon-next _2Cx2VFM04V1vDEfkDEJ3Cw" ></span></div>
      <div class="activity-item activity-container"
        data-css="activity-item" >
        <div class="activity-text" data-css="activity-text" ><span >Content</span></div>
        <div class="activity-vote-count" data-css="activity-vote-count" ><span >0</span><span> vote</span></div>
        <div class="activity-reply-count"
          data-css="activity-reply-count" ><span>1</span><span> reply</span></div>
        <time datetime="Wed May 25 2016 15:57:21">
          <span >May 25, 2016, 3:57 PM</span></time></div>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is my css (in less)

```
.expander-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.expand-anchor {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-self: center;

  &:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

.icon-next:before {
  content: ">";
}

.arrow:before {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform .25s ease-out;

  .expand& {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }

}

.top-comment-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.reply-container {
  display: flex;
}

// activity-item
.activity-item {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.reply-item {
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.activity-container {
  display: flex;
}
.activity-text {
  align-self: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex: 5;
  // flex-basis: 100;
}
.activity-vote-count {
  align-self: center;
  // width: 10%;
  flex: 1;
}
.activity-reply-count {
  align-self: flex-end;
  // flex-basis: 1;
  // width: 10%;
  flex: 1;
}
.activity-container {
  align-self: center;
}
```

What I want to achieve is to have all these elements aligned on a single axis.

e.g.

```
> Content                           0 vote   1 reply  May 25, 2016, 3:57 PM
```

However as you can see in my codepen coode (http://codepen.io/kongakong/pen/YWKvgG?editors=1100), the arrow somehow occupies one line by itself. The rest of content is squeezed to the next line.

I have tried a few thing e.g. add `flex-basis`, `flex-wrap: nowrap` etc but they do not have any effect.

[image]

A second question is how can I have finer control on the placement? I want the text 'Content' to occupy most of the space in a row. Information such as vote and time should be moved to the right hand side. I have applied the 'flex-grow:1' to the text but it does not grow and fill the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex row works by aligning its immediate children in a row. You have your elements nested too deeply. Everything you want on the same row needs to be siblings. You can see some work I've done with flex for reference http://codepen.io/steezeburger/pen/LNEaKv

```
<div class="flex-row">

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="flex-column skinny">
        <span class="flex-vertical-center af af-icon" data-bind="css: action_color">
           <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="flex-column">
        <span class="af af-action">New Order</span>
        <span class="af af-name">John Carmack</span>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="flex-column">
      <span class="af af-time-lapsed">13m ago</span>
      <span class="af af-value">$65</span>
    </div>


</div>
```

This is a bit more advanced as I have nested columns in my rows, but you can see above that .wrapper and the last .flex-column div will be on the same row. Check out the codepen for a clearer example.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
 <style>
        .top-comment-container {
            width: 40em;
        }
        .alternate-color {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .activity-item {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .abcd {
            display: flex;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="expander-container" data-css="expander-container">
        <div class="top-comment-container" data-css="top-comment-container">
            <a class="expand-anchor" data-css="expand-anchor">
                <div><span class="alternate-color icon-next arrow" data-css="alternate-color icon-next _2Cx2VFM04V1vDEfkDEJ3Cw"></span></div>
                <div class="activity-item activity-container" data-css="activity-item">
                    <div class="activity-text" data-css="activity-text"><span>Content</span></div>
                    <div class="abcd">
                        <div class="activity-vote-count" data-css="activity-vote-count"><span>0</span><span> vote</span></div>
                        <div class="activity-reply-count" data-css="activity-reply-count"><span>1</span><span> reply</span></div>
                        <time datetime="Wed May 25 2016 15:57:21">
                            <span>May 25, 2016, 3:57 PM</span>
                        </time>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

apply margins as you like..